# i tried 2 style of nested loop in golang, but it has different output

Tags: for-loop, go, nested-loops

i have this quiz, you should make an output like this, and i search youtube tutorials for "for golang" and it explain that it has 2 style of for in golang,

1
21
11
12
13
14
22
11
12
13
14
23
11
12
13
14
24
11
12
13
14
2
21
11
12
13
14
22
11
12
13
14
23
11
12
13
14
24
11
12
13
14
3
21
11
12
13
14
22
11
12
13
14
23
11
12
13
14
24
11
12
13
14
4
21
11
12
13
14
22
11
12
13
14
23
11
12
13
14
24
11
12
13
14
5
21
11
12
13
14
22
11
12
13
14
23
11
12
13
14
24
11
12
13
14

it should be vertically outputted, not horizontally, so i build 3 variable, i = 1, j = 21, and k = 11, and i use for to automatically increase the value, the 1st style worked, but the 2nd style somehow its different

yt vid : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ-llP_yKNo on 5:28 min he explain that for has 2 style

1st style :

```
for i:=1; i <= 5; i++{
        fmt.Println(i)
        for j:=21; j <= 24; j++ {
            println(j)
            for k:=11; k<=14; k++ {
                fmt.Println(k)
            }
        }
    }
```

2nd style :

```
i:=1
j:=21
k:=11

for i <= 5{
    fmt.Println(i)
    i++
    for j <= 24 {
        println(j)
        j++
        for k<=14 {
            fmt.Println(k)
            k++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im still new on this programming :)

Comment: The third statement in the for loop is evaluated *after* each loop. Putting the same statement at the *start* of the loop body is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the syntax but about your logic.

In the 1st style with `for i := ...`, whenever next loop run, you reset the value to the init state, means it always sets `j` to 21 and `k` to 11. So there will a many sub loop runs.

In contrast, 2nd style, you init value `j` and `k` right before going to loop. So in the second loop of `i`, `j` and `k` are still the same value with 25 and 15 in that order.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to print the output in the golang.

`fmt.Println` appends a new line in the end.
`fmt.Printf` prints content as it is.

For more details read the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).

```
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%v ", i)
        for j := 21; j <= 24; j++ {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", j)
            for k := 11; k <= 14; k++ {
                fmt.Printf("%v ", k)
            }
        }
    }
```

Output

```
1 21 11 12 13 14 22 11 12 13 14 23 11 12 13 14 24 11 12 13 14 2 21 11 12 13 14 22 11 12 13 14 23 11 12 13 14 24 11 12 13 14 3 21 11 12 13 14 22 11 12 13 14 23 11 12 13 14 24 11 12 13 14 4 21 11 12 13 14 22 11 12 13 14 23 11 12 13 14 24 11 12 13 14 5 21 11 12 13 14 22 11 12 13 14 23 11 12 13 14 24 11 12 13 14
```

To add a new line use the `\n` escape sequence.

Check the running code [link](https://play.golang.org/p/dg3eZDBKTno)